# validate a date on the basis of locale argument (intl api)

Tags: javascript, html, validation, date, ecmascript-6

I have an inputfield. The locale argument is defined in the beginning. The problem is now, that I want to validate the input on the basis of the locale argument.
For example when the locale is `'en-uk'` then the date has to be like `7/25/2018` but when the locale is `'de-ch'` is has to be `25.7.2018`.
Has anybody a smooth solution for this?

Comment: The "locale" is actually a language code, which is an unreliable way to determine the order in which date components are typically presented. Systems also usually allow users to specify whatever date format they want. Where I live, people usually write short dates with only numbers as d/m/y, but in long format as mmmm do, yyyy. Far better to tell the user the format you expect in an unambiguous way and validate against that.

Comment: It's a lot more complex than that. The contentteam can set the local in adobe experience manager, because it should be a different locale for each country my component will be used. Due to this have to expect every date format.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;

if(locale=='de-ch'){
  $('#yourInputBoxHere').mask("9.9.9999", {placeholder: 'D.M.YYYY' });

}else if(locale=='someAnotherLanguage'){
  //Another Mask
}
```

OR

```html
    <div>
        <label for="party-time">Date/time:</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" id="party-time"
               name="party-time" value="2018-06-12T19:30"
               min="2018-06-07T00:00" max="2018-06-14T00:00" />
    </div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

Comment: A good answer should explain how it solves the OP's issue. You seem to be suggesting the the OP develop a language mask for every language and dialect. I don't think that's reasonable given the the Intl object provides a way to do that (`new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale).formatToParts()`). The second example doesn't seem to meet the OP's requirements at all.